# Nikon AF-S 55-300mm VR vs. Tamron SP 70-300mm VC USD

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, tamron

I am planning to buy a entry level telephoto zoom lens for my D5100.

I have boiled down to two lenses: The Nikon AF-S 55-300mm VR and the TAMRON SP 70-300mm VC USD.

My question is: Is the Tamron better than the Nikon lens given that it costs about $100 more? I'm on a tight budget and wont be doing any serious photography.

Comment: "Is it better" often depends on circumstances, and "is it worth the price difference is subjective". However, questions comparing specific lenses for a specific purpose are on topic — see [this meta discussion](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/what-about-review-this-item-please-questions). Please edit your question with that in mind, describing what you're hoping to _do_ with the lens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the Tamron SP 70-300mm Di VC USD (Amazon -> 223€) for my Nikon D5100.  I'm satisfied with it, the stabilizator is awesome.

A sample: https://500px.com/photo/61807535/cyclo-cross-sprinter-2-by-salva-j-garc%C3%ADa-barroso

Reasons I found to buy the Tamrom:

- Tamron VC is superior to Nikon VR.
- Nikon is weaker in range 250-300.
- There is a non written Law in zoom lenses: "More focal length range worst optical quality"
- Tamron 70-300 is more near to Nikon 70-300 quality, but it's far forward from Nikon 55-300.
- The diference costs between Tamron and Nikon 55-300 ($100) is low compared with the diference costs between Tamron and Nikon 70-300 ($250), the real competitor.

See this comparation tests from DXOMark. [DXOMARK test lenses](http://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Compare/Side-by-side/SP-70-300mm-F4-5.6-Di-VC-USD-Nikon-versus-AF-S-NIKKOR-55-300mm-f-4.5-5.6G-DX-ED-VR-versus-AF-S-VR-Zoom-Nikkor-70-300mm-f-4.5-5.6G-IF-ED___281_0_324_0_262_0)